# TradingView Strategy alertcondition() not being triggered but shapes are being plotted

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I have a PineScript in version 3 that I'm trying to get an alert when there is a buy signal. I debugged with added in a plotshape(), which is in fact appearing on the chart. I also did created an alert in TradingView itself of the specific strategy.

```
// Create short sell and buy conditions
shortSell = crossover(close, resistance)
buy = crossunder(close, support)

// Plot the buy and sell signals
plotshape(shortSell, color=red, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, text="SS")
plotshape(buy, color=green, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny, text="B")

// Alert when price crosses the resistance or support line
alertcondition(shortSell)
alertcondition(buy)
```

any help would be appreciated, since the shapes are being plotted, which in turn should follow along with an alert.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this just by doing a small work around.

I changed the strategy() to a study() and created an alert trigger that is "Once Per Bar Close"